# How do I properly escape these quotes?

Tags: python, escaping

I want to create a code object for the following selection:

```
"LAND1"= 'Park / Recreation / Open Space' AND "LAND2"= 'Park / Recreation / Open Space'
```

I have tried:

```
code_string = """"LAND1"= 'Park / Recreation / Open Space' AND "LAND2"= 'Park / Recreation / Open Space'"""
code_obj = compile(code_string,'<string>', 'exec')
```

This gives an error. Is there a way to retain the double qoutes for the LAND1 and LAND2? How would I use format in this regard?

Comment: How could you assign a string to another string? That doesn't make sense, of course there's an error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's supposed to be one string literal

Comment: @cat but then the OP is trying to compile it as code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this question's title is terrible; I changed it to "How do I properly escape these quotes" but it's pending. Can you change it / approve the edit?

Comment: @cat no, because it's not clear that this is what the OP is actually asking. You're completely ignoring the second line of their code.

Comment: wunderkind if an answer has solved your question please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What about the following:

```
>>> code_string = """"LAND1"= 'Park / Recreation / Open Space' AND "LAND2"= 'Park / Recreation / Open Space'"""
>>> code_string
'"LAND1"= \'Park / Recreation / Open Space\' AND "LAND2"= \'Park / Recreation / Open Space\''
```

Answer (score 0):

If Idos' answer isn't what you wanted, maybe this is?

```
>>> string = "LAND1 = 'Park / Recreation / Open Space'; LAND2 = 'Park / Recreation / Open Space'"
>>> exec(string)
>>> LAND1
'Park / Recreation / Open Space'
>>> LAND2
'Park / Recreation / Open Space'
```

Stick to one kind of quotes. Moreover, since you're `exec`'ing it, there can't be quotes on the Left-hand-side of the `exec`'d equals sign, because assigning to a string literal doesn't make any sense.